# SPARC architecture syscall assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, operating-system, system-calls, sparc

From man 2 syscall:

```
   The  first  table lists the instruction used to transition to kernel mode 
   (which might not be the fastest or best way to transi‐
   tion to the kernel, so you might have to refer to vdso(7)), the register used to indicate 
   the system call number,  the  register
   used to return the system call result, and the register used to signal an error.

   arch/ABI    instruction           syscall #  retval  error    Notes
   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   ...
   sparc/32    t 0x10                g1         o0      psr/csr  [1]
   sparc/64    t 0x6d                g1         o0      psr/csr  [1]
   ...
```

When I review samples of assembly performing syscalls on SPARC, I see two different methods to transition into the kernel:

- `t 0x10` (as suggested from the man pages)
- `ta 8`

Two random examples:

- https://linuxsecurity.com/resource_files/documentation/virus-writing-HOWTO/_html/sparc-debian2.2-linux/language.of.evil.html
- https://unix4lyfe.org/hello-sparc/

However, I don't see the `t` instruction anywhere in SPARC Architecture manual. Instead I see a family of trap instructions (the Ticc instructions), which includes the "trap always" `ta` instruction.

From the SPARC manual (https://www.gaisler.com/doc/sparcv8.pdf):

```
A Ticc instruction evaluates the integer condition codes (icc) according to
the cond field of the instruction, producing either a “true” or “false” result.
If “true” and no higher priority exceptions or interrupt requests are pending,
then a trap_instruction trap is generated. If “false”, a trap_instruction trap
does not occur and the instruction behaves like a NOP.

If a trap_instruction trap is generated, the tt field of the Trap Base Register
(TBR) is written with 128 plus the least significant seven bits of “r[rs1] +
r[rs2]” if the i field is zero, or 128 plus the least significant seven bits of
“r[rs1] + sign_ext(software_trap#)” if the i field is one.

After a taken Ticc, the processor enters supervisor mode, disables traps,
decrements the CWP (modulo NWINDOWS), and saves PC and nPC into
r[17] and r[18] (local registers 1 and 2) of the new window. See Chapter 7,
“Traps.”
```

I'm trying to understand which entry of the TBR is used by each version of these syscalls. Since all the software traps are at 0x80 -- 0xFF, it must be one of those. There are two rules outlined in the Ticc family:

- 128 plus the least significant seven bits of “r[rs1] + r[rs2]” if the i field is zero
- 128 plus the least significant seven bits of “r[rs1] + sign_ext(software_trap#)” if the i field is one

Can anyone explain the difference between `t 0x10` and `ta 8`? In particular, can you explain which of those rules is applied and the value of the TBR offset being used in each case?

Comment: `t` is the same as `ta`. You don't need to type out the "always" in certain assemblers. Verify machine code.

Comment: The two forms the manual talks about are the immediate vs register operand. E.g. `ta 0x10` vs. `ta %i0`

Comment: So, one calls TBR[128+16] and the other calls TBR[128+8], and the generic syscall handler is in _both_ those slots (so they do the same thing)?  Or, am I making some strange math error and 0x10 and 8 are the same...